# How to see certificate for intermediate CA in Keychain?

Tags: security, keychain, certificate, smime

When I check details of a certificate I only see information about the certificate itself. Is there any way to see the issuer’s certificate? In my case it’s an intermediate CA. The certificate that I care is for S/MIME (hence the tag), but I think this should apply to all kinds of certificates in general.

I think there should be a way because it’s very intuitive in Windows. Also Chrome on macOS displays the full chain for websites. I think Keychain.app has this information because it labels the certificate as a verified one.

Comment: Are you trying to see a website certificate? Or any other certificate stored on your computer?

Comment: @Prado No, not a website certificate from browser. I want the one already in my Keychain.app. But if you have a way to view it with browser then that’s good solution, too. (I doubt it, though.)

Comment: To view it in browser, it needs to be a TLS certificate, instead of code-sign or S/MIME. In addition, the website needs to serve it; if the website renewed the certificate then this path is dead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Evaluate Certificate

1. Launch the **Keychain Access.app**
2. Select the certificate of interest
3. Select the menu item: **Keychain Access (menu) > Certificate Assistant (sub-menu) > Evaluate "*certificate name*"…**
4. Select **Continue** to choose *Generic evaulation (certificate chain validation only)*
5. Select **Show Certificate…** button

You can now navigate through the certificate chain and view the leaf, intermediate, and root certificate details.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### For any Stored certificate, using Keychain Utility:

Open Keychain Utility, choose any certificate, double click it, select Detais:

[image]

The certificate will popup up, click on Details triangle.

[image]

Look for the issuer on the info below:

[image]

Here is the same certificate showed above, with the window extended to show full information: (NOTE: this **osu.edu certificate** is EXPIRED, so it is shown as "not trusted", but its issuer chain is present on it, and it is valid [the issuer InCommon CA chain].

[image]

---

### Here is an Intermediate CA Certificate stored on my Keychain:

[image]

Here is another Intermediate CA Certificate

[image]

---

### For any website certificate, using Safari:

[image]

After clicking "Show Certificate", folow the same procedure and click on the Details Triangle.

Comment: How can I jump from a leaf certificate to its intermediate CA certificate? That’s the whole point of my question. In your example, how can I see the certificate for “InCommon RSA Server CA” without going to the website? As I mentioned in question comment, the website may choose to serve a new certificate, so the last method won’t work in some cases.

Comment: If the certificate is stored on your Keychain, just scroll down the details window and you will find it on down almost at the botton, along with the Issuer and the URI of the InCommonRSAServerCA

Comment: Could you be more specific? I only see the certificate extensions at the bottom. Is it in the screenshots?

Comment: I extended the pictures to show all information of the certificates